# Python YAML Integer Attributes

Tags: python, yaml

My yaml file as the following data

```
name:
    'head1':
        1: 39032
        3: 4920
        11: 313
     'head2':
        4:490
        11:4924
```

File total length is 10Mb but format is similar to above pattern. When I use yaml.load to load this file it craps out!

After 2 mins memory usage in htop shows 80%. Probably this might have to do with having integer attributes 1:, 3: etc in the file. But should it crash out for this formatting issue? File also crashes in Matlab too....

```
import yaml
t1 = open('test.yml','r')
newt1 = yaml.load(t1)
```

Comment: Are you sure your yaml format is ok (spaces and so..)? also do you have any trace-back error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the format was wrong....

```
'head1':
    1: 39032
    3: 4920
    11: 313
```

Instead of 1,3, 11 I changed them to quoted strings.     'head1':
        '1': 39032
        '3': 4920
        '11': 313

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if you were using a pure-python yaml parser. Try one with a c-backend to improve performance and memory usage.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18026176/1234176) for examples.